# Android gridview with row separators

Tags: android, gridview

I want use gridView of many images with CursorAdapter for best performance. Some items should be separated from each other. Finally it should be looks like http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/? but with grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do it but you have to implement Jeff Shrkey's [SeparatedListAdapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

There isn’t an easy way of creating these separated lists, so I’ve put together SeparatedListAdapter which does it quickly. To summarize, we’re creating a new BaseAdapter that can contain several other Adapters, each with their own section headers.

Comment: Your example works only for a ListView, but i want do it with gridView.